# Fully functioning web application with just ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase

I've built some web app with backend technology like node/express and Rails. A few days ago I started messing with the frontend Reactjs and I love it a lot. I see that we can navigate to different part of the app via React Router and Link, base on what I understand, this is similar to node/express when we do app.get('/route', cb). After a while I found out I can't send email or access database with react alone, I needed a server, I needed node/express. Then I looked into google firebase, google provided real time db, authentication, file uploading and mailing... and I heard it works great with react. So my question, if I skip node/express, can I build a fully working web app with just Reactjs and google firebase? If I can, what are the pros and cons?

If I want, can I build facebook, twitter, youtube with react and firebase?

Comment: yes you can build an app with reactjs having firebase handle backend.

Answer (score -1):

> So my question, if i skip node/express, can i build a fully working web app with just Reactjs and google firebase?

Yes

> If i can, what are the pros and cons?

Covered quite a lot. Here is an old blog post : https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html

Short answer : You can build features provided by firebase yourself, but its generally cheaper to just use it as a service.